# How can i add column names to the ResultSet. I use Java with the EntityManager

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, entitymanager

Is it possible to read out the columnnames?

My Application: Java, SpringBoot, JPA, Hibernate

My code:

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(
          "select name as Name, concat('Time:',time, ' AND:', event) as FOO 
          from XYZ
          where NAME = 'BLA'");
List<Object[]> resultList = query.getResultList();
```

I need the columnnames (Name and FOO) in the first Object[] of the ResultSet or
somewhere else...

My unsightly solution:

```
private String getColumnNames(String sql) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String part1 = sql.split("from")[0];

    part1 = part1.replaceAll("\\(.*?\\)", "");

    String[] columns = part1.split(",");
    for (String column : columns) {
        String alias = column;
        if (column.toUpperCase().contains(" AS ")) {
            alias = column.toUpperCase().split(" AS ")[1];
        }
        alias = alias.replace("'","");
        sb.append(alias+",");
    }

    String columnNames = sb.toString();
    if (columnNames.length() != 0) {
        columnNames = columnNames.substring(0, columnNames.length()-1);
    }

    return columnNames;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: The admin can store a statemant like this in DB. So i can not create a Mapping class because i have only the SQL-String.

Answer (score 2):

You should use other overloaded versions of `createNativeQuery()` :

```
public Query createNativeQuery(String sqlString, Class resultClass);
```

or

```
public Query createNativeQuery(String sqlString, String resultSetMapping);
```

In this way, you could map the result of the query to a class that contains `name` and `foo` fields.

For example with the first way :

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(
          "select name as Name, concat('Time:',time, ' AND:', event) as FOO 
          from XYZ
          where NAME = 'BLA'", Xyz.class);
List<Xyz> resultList = query.getResultList();
```

Note that `query.getResultList()` will return a raw type.

Comment: The admin can store a statemant like this in DB. So i can not create a Mapping class because i have only the SQL-String.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do here is to:

1. First create an entity with `Name` and `FOO` attributes, so you can map it as a result of `query.getResultList()`.
2. Then map it with a `List<YourEntity>` instead of `List<Object[]`.
3. And Last thing is to define a mapper for the request so it can map those results to the desired entity, **if the query uses different attributes names other than the ones in the entity**, using  [**@SqlResultSetMapping**](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/SqlResultSetMapping.html).

You can check this [**Hibernate Tips: How to map native query results to entities** tutorial](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-map-native-query-results-entities/) for further details.

**Edit:**

If you can't create a new `Entity` to map the results, you can map those results in a `HashMap` in each element of the `Object[]` like this:

```
Map results = new HashMap();

results.put("Name", obj[0]);
results.put("Foo", obj[1]);
```

Comment: The admin can store a statemant like this in DB. So i can not create a Mapping class because i have only the SQL-String.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Lets assume your entity name is XYZ and you Repository would be XYZRepository, Lets create a DTO which only contains name and eventDetais since we want to extract only these 2 details from table.

```
public class XyzDTO {
    String name;
    String eventDetails;
    public XyzDTO() {
    }
    public XyzDTO(String name, String eventDetails) {
     this.name = name;
     this.eventDetails =eventDetails;
    }
}
```

This code would be written in XYZRepository.

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true)
List<Details> getList();
```

This code would be written in XYZ entity.

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "getList",
        classes = @ConstructorResult(targetClass = XyzDTO.class,
            columns = {@ColumnResult(name = "name", type = String.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "eventDetails", type = String.class)}))
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "XYZ.getList",
        query = "select name as name, concat('Time:',time, ' AND:', event) as eventDetails from XYZ where name = 'BL")
public class XYZ implements Serializable {

}
```